# Gauss-Jordan elimination for systems of power equations

Tags: nonlinear-system

I'm curious as to whether Gauss-Jordan elimination has an equivalent approach for systems of equations involving **non-linear** terms, for example:

$$
\begin{align}
x^3 y^3 z^3 &= 1\\
xy^5 z^3 &= 2\\
xy^3 z^5 &= 3
\end{align}
$$

I can solve these equations manually by reducing the terms, but I'm struggling to find a matrix form (does one exist?) to represent it in.

Comment: *Nonlinear* is too broad. *Polynomial* is the keyword. Also, take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchberger%27s_algorithm

Comment: In your particular case, take logarithms on both sides, and you get a linear algebra problem with variables $\log x, \log y, \log z$.